# How to split/divide array using user input

Tags: c, arrays, computer-science

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( )
{
    int length = 0;
    int divide = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int i;

    printf("Set the length of array: \n");
    scanf("%d", &length);
    int array[length];

    for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }
    printf("Divide array into subarray: \n");
    scanf("%d", &divide);
    for(i = 0; i < divide; i++)
    {
        int countfrom = length / divide * i;
        int countto = countfrom + length / divide;

        for(int j = countfrom; j < countto; j++)
        {
            if( array[j] == 1 && array[j+1] == 0 && array[j+2] == 1)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("count: %d\n", count);
    return 0; 
}
```

This is what I have so far. The purpose is to define the length of array from user input and divide it into subarray (int divide is also from the user input).
The main purpose is to count the number of times the sequence, 101 is found in the divided subarray. It works well, except for the value that is odd. For example, `array[length(value: 17)] = {1, 0, 1, 2, 7, 9, 6, 5, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0}`, and if the divide value is 5, then the subarrays should be,
`{1, 0, 1}, {2, 7, 9}, {6, 5, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 0}`, and the value for the count should be 3. However, it prints out four.

Comment: You should work together with your classmate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44113321/how-to-find-subsequences-in-an-array Note we are not a coding/tutoring service. Do you have a **specific** question about your code?

Comment: I think the problem in that code is in the condtion, array[j]... is there any idea how to fix it?

Comment: `{1, 0, 1, 2, 7, 9, 6, 5, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0} and if the divide value is 5, then the subarrays should be, {1, 0, 1}, {2, 7, 9}, {6, 5, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 0}` is typo. 1st fix it. Also Your code is accessing out-of-bounds.

Comment: So why do you have two identities and double post the same question? That's against site-rules!

Comment: I only count ***two*** appearances of `{1, 0, 1}` among the subarrays as you presented them.  Why, then, should the output count be 3?

Comment: @JohnBollinger I'm guessing the sample input was supposed to have been `1,0,1,2,7,9,6,5,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0`

Comment: actually, the sample input does demonstrate the problem, producing 3 instead of 2.  but the subarrays originally given were wrong

Answer (score -1):

I initially was misinterpreting "101 is found in the divided subarray" as meaning the subarray would have to actually be 101.  the j loop is indeed needed if you want to search the subarray, but you do need a bounds check.

```
         if( array[j] == 1 && array[j+1] == 0 && array[j+2] == 1)
```

should be

```
        if( j+2 < countto && array[j] == 1 && array[j+1] == 0 && array[j+2] == 1)
```

(or you can initially decrement countto by 2 and adjust it tto at most length-2).

Original answer:

From your description, it doesn't look like you need the j loop or countto at all; in the i loop, you should just be checking `array[countfrom]==1 && array[countfrom+1]==0 && array[countfrom+2]==1` (and also first checking that countfrom + 2 < length so you don't go past the end of your array).

But then your code is assuming you have "subarrays" of length 3; you should check that that is actually true given the input, and give an error message if it is not.